# Запятая перед союзом "да и"

Tags: пунктуация

> Отделяются или выделяются запятыми вводимые союзом «да и»
>   присоединительные конструкции (слова или предложения), содержащие
>   дополнительные замечания или разъяснения к сказанному ранее.
>
> *День и план наступления держались в строжайшей тайне. Но то, что оно готовится, скрыть было невозможно, да и не надо было скрывать.* Л.
>   Брежнев, Малая земля. *На станции оставался только один передатчик, да
>   и тот старый.*

**[ДА И, *союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_151)**

Цитата из правила приведена не полностью; "мой" ли это случай (в оригинале запятой не было)?

> Действительно, помочь актёру аффективная память может только на
>   съёмочной площадке, да и то при условии наличия рядом так называемого
>   «тренера», то есть человека, который помогает обнаружить среди твоих
>   эмоциональных воспоминаний именно то, что наиболее подходит к
>   конкретному событию в кадре и помогает его полноценно раскрыть в
>   индивидуальной репетиции.

У меня три "то" в предложении - как же ж жить? Бережём автора, максимально "его" сохраняя.

...*именно то, что = именно такое, которое*?

Тогда *человека, который помогает* заменяем на *человека, помогающего*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед "да и" запятая верна - присоединение, а что даёт Ваша замена придаточного на причастный оборот? ТО ведь не убирается, а ТО ЕСТЬ легко убирается без изменения смысла. Предложение длинное, тире поможет разбить его на две части:

*Действительно, помочь актёру аффективная память может только на съёмочной площадке, да и то при условии наличия рядом так называемого «тренера» -  человека, который помогает обнаружить среди твоих эмоциональных воспоминаний именно то, что наиболее подходит к конкретному событию в кадре и помогает его полноценно раскрыть в индивидуальной репетиции.*